# Multiple if/else statements not producing the desired output

Tags: java, if-statement

I am trying to write a program that forms a random 2 character word and then asks the user to guess the word. After the user inputs a guess, the program should check the guess with the answer. The program should then give the user a hint depending on their guess in the form nAkB where nA is the right letters in the right position and kB is the right letters but in the wrong position. My problem is that my program won't show the hint when their are right letters but in the wrong position (say the answer is aD and the user guesses Dc) the output should be "Hint: 0A1B". Here is my code for the getHint Method:

```
public static String getHint(String guess, String answer){
    String hint = "No";

    if(guess.charAt(0) == answer.charAt(0) && guess.charAt(1) == answer.charAt(1)){
        hint = "You win!";
    }
    else if(guess.charAt(0) == answer.charAt(0) && guess.charAt(1) != answer.charAt(1)){
        hint = "Hint: 1A0B";

    }
    else if(guess.charAt(0) != answer.charAt(0) && guess.charAt(1) == answer.charAt(1)){
        hint = "Hint: 1A0B";

    }
    else if(guess.charAt(0) == answer.indexOf(guess.charAt(0)) && guess.charAt(1) == answer.indexOf(guess.charAt(1))){
        hint = "Hint: 0A2B";

    }
    else if(guess.charAt(0) == answer.charAt(0) && guess.charAt(1) == answer.indexOf(guess.charAt(1)) &&
            guess.charAt(1) != answer.charAt(1)){
        hint = "Hint: 1A1B";

    }
    else if(guess.charAt(1) == answer.charAt(1) && guess.charAt(0) == answer.indexOf(guess.charAt(0)) &&
            guess.charAt(0) != answer.charAt(0)){
        hint = "Hint: 1A1B";

    }
    else if(guess.charAt(0) == answer.indexOf(guess.charAt(0)) && guess.charAt(0) != answer.charAt(0) &&
            guess.charAt(1) != answer.indexOf(guess.charAt(1)) && guess.charAt(1) != answer.charAt(1)){
        hint = "Hint: 0A1B";

    }
    else if(guess.charAt(1) == answer.indexOf(guess.charAt(1)) && guess.charAt(1) != answer.charAt(1) &&
            guess.charAt(0) == answer.indexOf(guess.charAt(0)) && guess.charAt(0) != answer.charAt(0)){
        hint = "Hint: 0A1B";

    }
    else{
        hint = "Hint: 0A0B";

    }


    return hint;
```

It never outputs anything with a 1B or 2B. It only does 1A0B or 0A0B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is code like `guess.charAt(0) == answer.indexOf(guess.charAt(0))` . `indexOf` will return the index of the character. So you are comparing the index of a character (rhs) to the ASCII value of the character (lhs) and your `if` statements using this `indexOf` construction are not being entered.

Rather, consider something like this:

```
else if(answer.indexOf(guess.charAt(0))!=-1 && answer.indexOf(guess.charAt(1)) != -1{
    hint = "Hint: 0A2B";

}
```

From [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)), `indexOf` returns `-1` if the given character is not found within the string.

Comment: Yes! This was the problem. Thank you so much for the help!